# Как вывести все поля записи, зная айди объекта?

Tags: django

Не могу вывести все поля локации, хотя айди локации выводит.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', loc_base, name='loc_base'),
    path('(<location_id>)', one, name='one'),    
]
```

view:

```
def one(request, location_id):
    location = Location.objects.get(id=location_id)
    context = {
        "location": location
    }
    return render(request, 'one_lok.html', context)
```

model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    # names own locations, 
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, 
                                     null=True, default=None)
    # Строковая строчка описание локации                                  
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    # Строковая строчка описание локации сокращенная
    short_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    price_per_day = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, 
                                        max_digits=10, default=0)
    # скрывет/показывает активные(не) локации(предложения)                                    
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)   #
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)   #

    def __str__(self):  # в админке меняет отображение
        # % s - принимает значения, Графа локации
        return '%s, %s' % (self.customer_name, self.price_per_day)

    class Meta:  # склонения названия
        verbose_name = 'Локация'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Локации'
```

html:

```
{% block locations %}

       <h1> TEST CUST 2 </h1>

       {{ location.id }}

       {% for location in locations %}

       <h1> TEST CUST 1 </h1>

       {{ location.id }}

       {% endfor %}

{% endblock locations %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить все данные определенной записи, вам нужно просто вручную перебрать эти поля.

**html**

```
{% block locations %}
  <h1> TEST CUST 2 </h1>
  {{ location.id }}
  {{ location.customer_name }}
  {{ location.description }}
  {{ location.short_description }}
  {{ location.price_per_day
  ....
{% endblock locations %}
```

Comment: таким образом оно выводит все доступные локации по айди, а нужна одна но полная(картинка, опись, начинка)

Comment: вам нужны все данные определённой локации?

Comment: да, в вытащить с бд всю инфу по данному запросу(айди)

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: хм, как вариант. но разве нельзя подвязать под id вывод всего?

Comment: Вряд ли. По крайней мере, я такого не встречал. Да и незачем это.